# Sharp UILabel after zooming image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel, uifont

I don't know what to ask exactly. I put a text on an UIImage (with aspect fit content) and save it to album.  If saved image is same size as aspect content mode then "text" seems OK.  But after zooming in that image, text on that image gets blurred. I want it to be sharp also. Is it possible to do that?

Is it possible to increase pixel count per point? Or What should I do?

Edit: I think I need to increase font size without increasing frame. Is it possible to increase font size (for example from 20 to 50) without changing label's frame size.

Thank you.

Comment: So are you fitting the text to the true image size, or downsizing the image to fit the text? Show some code and sample images.

Comment: I'm fitting the text to the true image size. I will give sample images.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is saved as a bitmap, there's not much you can do. The best suggestion I can make is to render it at larger than the target size and save THAT to the photo album. Normally it will be scaled smaller, which looks good. Then when the user zooms in, the text will still be sharp because you will be revealing text rendered at the larger size.

The down-side, of course, is file size and memory footprint. Larger images take more storage, more memory, and more CPU horsepower to display.

I seriously doubt if the iOS photo album supports any vector formats (PDF, illustrator, etc.) If they did that would be another possibility, but like I said, probably not.